# Comments are mixed in questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Look at the comments from [How to display all details if user selects 'All' option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610396/how-to-display-all-details-if-user-selects-all-option) question.

They're not related at all with the question.

Comment: Check the rev history, the OP drastically changed the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14610396/revisions

Comment: Of course - I should trust more SO than some users :-) Thanks for the enlightng..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few deleted comments, so the remaining ones didn't really make much sense out of context.

I removed a few more, so it should look more coherent now.

When you come across this, just flag the comments that seem irrelevant for moderator attention and a moderator (or a few more flags from other users like you) will clean them up.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks for making it make sense again, but perhaps there's [more to investigate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166121/194906).

Answer (score 2):

The seemingly unrelated comments aren't a bug, they're because the OP made a massive edit completely changing the question topic. The perplexing comments related to the previous version.

I suspect the OP did this to circumvent the wait period on offering a bounty - this user has used 4 bounties in their brief 41 day time at SO, which seems a lot, and every time by editing an existing question to be a brand new one immediately before offering the bounty.

It's happened on all four bounty questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14337345/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14189739/revisions (revision 3)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14544657/revisions (revision 2), and the one you mentioned,
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14610396/revisions

Comment: I'm not *too* worried about this since the original questions didn't have any answers and weren't all that great. Now we have better questions and some answers on each. This is certainly a bit weird, but I'm not (yet) sure if I'd go as far as to call this an abuse of the edit/bounty mechanics. That said, thanks for digging further! I'll take care of this from here.